# find the value of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz?$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f(z)=z^3e^{z^2}$  for  $z \in \mathbb{C}$  and   let $C$ be the circle $z= e^{i\theta}$ , where $\theta$ varies  from $ 0$  to $4 \pi.$Then find $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz?$$

**My attempt** : I think by **Argument principle**$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz=3$$ because   $f(z)=z^3e^{z^2}$ has $3$ zeroes

Also ,by direct calculation  we have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C{2z} dz+ 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C\frac{3}{z} dz$$

After  that  im not able to proceed further

Comment: You're almost right—just note that $C$ winds twice around the unit circle.

Comment: In $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C{2z} dz+ 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C\frac{3}{z} dz$$ note that the first integral is $0$ and the second one has a simple pole at $z=0$ ... so find the residue there.

Comment: @GEdgar im not getting   why 
why $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C{2z} dz=0 $?

Comment: Integrate an analytic function around a closed curve, result is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These example shall only demonstrate how one may use the Argument Principle to calculate 'impossible' line integrals of the type
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz=(N_z)-(N_p)$$
Where $N_z ,N_p$ are respectively number of zeros and poles of f(z) inside the contour.
Now let's think about how we gonna find the zeros and poles. We gonna use the Rouche's Theorem. The theorem says that; Let C be simple closed contour and suppose that;

a) F(z) and G(z)are analytic inside and on C

b) |F(z)|>|G(z)| at each point on C.

F(z) and F(z)+G(z) have the same number of zeros.
So conditions are hold. Let start the solution.
$C$ be the circle $z= e^{i\theta}$, where 0 to 4${pi}$ means that |z|=1 (unit disk).
Now let H(z)= $(z^3).e^{z^2}$, F(z)=$(z^3).e^{z^2}$ and G(z)=0
Condition a) is hold and |F(1)|=$e^2$ and |G(1)|=0 obviously |F(1)|>|G(1)|
We can say that F and H (F(z)+G(z)) have the same number of zeros.
$(z^3).e^{z^2}$=0 => $e^{z^2}$ can never be equal to 0, so investigate the $z^3$=0.
This equation have 3 zeros obvious way in the contour.

So$(N_z)$=3 and $(N_p)$=0 because H is a analytic function.So the answer of the integral is

$(N_z)$-$(N_p)$=3.